# Override the config.js of Ckeditor + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I've configured the ckeditor gem on my Rails 4.1.6 app. I have override the `config.js` of Ckeditor for that I have created the config.js file in assets/ckeditor folder. Also added the asset path in `ckeditor.rb`

```
config.asset_path = "/assets/ckeditor/"
```

And in my application.js I have added the following code:

```
#= require ckeditor/init
#= require ckeditor/config
```

But still its not overriding the config.js file. Its not loading the overridden config.js file.

Please help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In case you didn't solve this by now, I have a similar situation.

First, check http://serveraddress/assets/ckeditor/config.js

If you get a sample config file, then delete /public/assets/ckeditor/config.js in production server, after precompile, and restart app. It works for me.